ASP.NET MVC Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:61071/
I get a problem using selenium in ASP.NET MVC (Web), when browser is opened, the selenium driver url cannot open 'https://www.google.com/' in the browser.
This is my full code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Timers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace myapp.Controllers
{
    public class myappTestController : Controller
    {
        // declare variables
        private static string binary_location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BinaryLocation"];

        private static ChromeOptions Options()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", download_path);
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

            return chromeOptions;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("myapptest")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(binary_location, Options());
                driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/";

                ViewBag.message = "";
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.message = ex.Message;
                return View();
            }       
        }        
        

    }
}

Anyone please help me to solve this problem, Thanks.
